# How to consume API and get typed response in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

How can I return a typed value as my response after consume REST API service properly?

Here is my JSON object which is produce by REST API:

```
[
  {
    "isDeleted": false,
    "reasonDeleted": null,
    "createdDate": "2020-12-31T07:34:09.918Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2021-02-17T11:34:45.643322Z",
    "createdBy": "superadmin2",
    "modifiedBy": "jans",
    "id": 1,
    "branchCode": "JKT",
    "branchName": "Jakarta",
    "branchHead": 1,
    "branchViceHead": 2,
    "isActive": true
  }
]
```

Here is my model:

```
export class Branch extends Audit {
    id: number;
    branchCode: string;
    branchName: string;
    branchHead: number;
    branchViceHead: number;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

and I want to consume my API with Angular, here is how I do it:

```
export class RESTService {

  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  post<T>(url: string, body?: any, header?: HttpHeaders, param?: HttpParams): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
    return this.http.post<T>(url, body,
      {
        headers: header ? header : this.headers,
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'json',
        params: param
      });
  }

}
```

I create RESTService class, so I can reuse it, and here is how I use it as Service:

```
export class BranchService {

  constructor(private rest: RESTService) { }

  listBySpecificId(branchIds: number[]): Observable<any> {
    const request: RequestResponse<number[]> = new RequestResponse<number[]>(branchIds);

    return this.rest.post<Branch[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}${endpoint.branch.view_by_specific_id}`, request);
  }
}
```

and here is how I execute the service:

```
fillDropList() {
    const listBranch = this.sharedService.currentUserValue.branch;
    let branches: Branch = new Branch();
    branches = this.branchService.listBySpecificId(listBranch);
    //going to do something for branches
}
```

but I get error in my syntax when I add the value to `branches`:

> TS2740: Type 'Observable ' is missing the following properties from
> type 'Branch': id, branchCode, branchName, branchHead, and 8 more.

How do I map my response to typed object that I created properly?

Comment: Well 1. `listBySpecificId` throws away the type information by returning `Observable<any>`, and 2. it returns an _observable_ of an _array_ of Branch, so there's no way you can assign that to a variable typed as Branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right, but the return of listBySpecificId is observable, so you need to receive the value with another form, like this:

```js
fillDropList() {
    const listBranch = this.sharedService.currentUserValue.branch;
    this.branchService.listBySpecificId(listBranch).subscribe((responseBranches) => {
      let branches = responseBranches
      //going to do something for branches
    });
    
}
```

Comment: for me it looks like `new Branch()` is useless as you have an assignment ` branches = ...`